# Partition Not Mounting On Bootup

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

I have a home server with my movies and what not on it. When I boot the PC it tells me that (media/Media/ is the drive) `/media/Media/` is not ready to mount or is not available (I don't know the exact words) so I pressed S to skip mounting and manually mounted it in GParted, which said it wasn't even set up, which I had already done when I first set up the server. I am going to post below the `/etc/fstab/` and `gksu blkid` and see if y'all can help me. It seems to be fine, but for some reason when I restart the computer it's as if I never set up the partition. Anyway, here it is:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="dd0448ac-2f22-4b55-9a5a-ebebef6cadbc" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Media" UUID="40F81DFF77FEAF2F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="d20a43cb-86f5-4d81-85a6-c4fc21248e11" TYPE="swap"
```

That is the `gksu blkid`. Here is the `/etc/fstab/`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc         proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid  0  0  
# / was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=dd0448ac-2f22-4b55-9a5a-ebebef6cadbc  /             ext4  errors=remount-ro    0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sdc5 during installation
UUID=d20a43cb-86f5-4d81-85a6-c4fc21248e11  none          swap  sw                   0  0  
/dev/sdb3                                  /media/Media  ntfs  defaults             0  0  
/dev/sda3                                  /media/Media  ntfs  defaults             0  0
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT/Correction: `media/Media` is NOT the drive, it is the partition on the drive with Ubuntu as well. Sorry my misuse of vocabulary

Comment: EDIT media/Media is NOT the drive, it is the partition on the drive with Ubuntu as well. Sorry my misuse of vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mount two different partitions `/dev/sdb3` and `/dev/sda3` on the same mount point `/media/Media`. Create a new folder under `/media` (e.g. `Media2`) and edit your `fstab` to mount the second partition on that.